# Plot for DSolve in mathematica

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, boundary-conditions

I don't Plot it's not working!!, can you help me?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eqn = {(y'[t]/y[t])^2 + k (1 - 2/3 b)/(y[t]^2) + f/3 == 0}
sol = DSolve[{eqn, y[0] == 1}, y[t], t]
Plot[y[t] /. sol /. {k -> 0.002, b -> 1, f -> 7/10}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Did you look at result of `y[t] /. sol /. {k -> 0.002, b -> 1, f -> 7/10}` before plotting it?  You will see it has complex numbers.   So you can't plot it. Need to plot its abs or real or imaginary parts. Whenever you have problem with expression or some result, it helps to look at it to see what is wrong.  So try `Plot[Abs[y[t] /. sol /. {k -> 0.002, b -> 1, f -> 7/10}], {t, 0, 10}]` and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = {(y'[t]/y[t])^2 + k (1 - 2/3 b)/(y[t]^2) + f/3 == 0};

sol = DSolve[{eqn, y[0] == 1} /. {k -> 1/500, b -> 1, f -> 7/10}, y[t], 
    t]; // Quiet
```

In general, the solutions are complex

```
y[t] /. sol /. {{t -> 0}, {t -> 5.}, {t -> 10.}}

(* {{1, 1}, {0.747595 + 0.665103 I, -0.747595 + 0.665103 I}, 
    {0.117796 + 0.994455 I, -0.117796 + 0.994455 I}} *)

ReImPlot[Evaluate[y[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]